# Area Under the Curve of the function $f$ defined on $[0, 1]$, where $f(0) = 0$ and, $f(x) = 2^n$, $x \in (2^{−2n}, 2^{−2n+2}], n = 1,2,....$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, area, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Consider the function $f$ defined on $[0, 1]$, where $f(0) = 0$ and, $f(x) = 2^n$, $x \in (2^{−2n}, 2^{−2n+2}], n = 1,2,....$

Compute the area under the curve, from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$. Does this Riemann integral of f exist formally?

---

I understand that the Riemann Integral can be defined by the Riemann Sum $\sum_{i=0}^n f(c_i)\Delta x_i$ where $c_i$ is any point in the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and $\Delta x_i = \dfrac{b - a}{n}$ represents the magnitude of the subintervals.

I also understand that in order for a function $f$ to be integrable it must be continuous over the closed interval $[a, b]$ or have finitely many discontinuities.

However, I do not know how to proceed in solving the problem. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to assist me in solving this problem and understanding the reasoning behind how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the length  of the intervall $(2^{-2n}, 2^{-2n+2}]$ is $3 \cdot2^{-2n}$ the area under the graph of $f$ on this interval is $2^n \times$ this expression which is $\frac{3}{2^n}$, which implies that the area under the graph is the sum over these expressions ($n=1\ldots\infty$). I would assume you have learned how to calculate this sum, if not do some research on the term geometric series.

If you have learned that, in order to be Riemann integrable (using the definition), the function has to be bounded, which it is not, since $2^n\rightarrow \infty$, which is another reason why this cannot be Riemann integrable. As pointed out in a comment the improper integral will exist, however.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer. Could you please enlighten me as to why the length of the interval is $3 \cdot2^{-2n}$?

Comment: @ThePointer $2^{-2n+2}-2^{-2n} = 2^{-2n}(4-1)$

Comment: @Thomas: Lebesgue's integrability criterion states that a *bounded* function is Riemann-integrable iff its set of dicontinuities is Lebesgue-null - which does happen in this case because every countable set is Lebesgue-null. The true problem, therefore, are not the discontinuities, but the unboundedness (which, among others, does not allow for the use of this theorem). Of course, the OP might be interested in the Lebesgue or improper Riemann integrability, in which case the answer would be affirmative.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance. Please excuse my novice-level questions, but I have another: Since, in order to be integrable, $f$ must be continuous over a *closed* interval $[a, b]$, and the function in the question is for $x \in (2^{−2n}, 2^{−2n+2}]$ (discontinuous at $2^{−2n}$), doesn't this immediately imply that the function in the question is not integrable?

Comment: @ThePointer: As said in my coment above: no, $f$ is integrable because it has ["few" discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for the response. But that is with regards to the function $f$: The function $f$ itself (the range of $f$) can have finitely many discontinuities. But the *interval* of $x$ must be a closed one, right? So we are not allowed discontinuities in the interval of $x$ (the domain of $f$), but we are allowed finitely many discontinuities in the range of $f$? If not, then where is my confusion?

Comment: @ThePointer: I swear that I don't see what discontinuities you see in that interval: $[0,1]$ is divided into smaller and smaller intervals, any two such consecutive intervals touching at the "common" endpoint - therefore there are no "holes" left.

Comment: @AlexM. My uncertainty comes from $x \in (2^{−2n}, 2^{−2n+2}]$. Doesn't the integral require closed interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$? But in this case, we have a discontinuity on the left side for $(2^{−2n}$?

Comment: @ThePointer: Ah, I see. No, that is a justified but needless precaution. Using Lebesgue's theorem stated above (or even weaker results), you may subtract "few" points from a closed interval and still be able to speak about the Riemann integral of $f$ on the resulting subset, so you don't need to worry about this aspect (proving things rigorously, though, would indeed require several pages).

Comment: @AlexM. Ahh, ok. My apologies. We have not yet studied these "Lebesque" concepts -- just Riemann. Thank you for the clarification.